# Xorg won't load/consider a driver that is present in /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/

Tags: x11, xorg, intel-graphics

Here are the drivers I have present on the system.

```
ls -l /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/
total 598
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 114176 Sep 10 12:43 ast_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23552 Sep 10 12:43 fbdev_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 359560 Sep 10 12:43 intel_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  86208 Sep 10 11:05 modesetting_drv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27624 Sep 10 12:43 vesa_drv.so
```

Here is the Xorg log, which shows that `intel_drv.so` isn't considered.

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep modules
[     5.258] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     5.399] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     5.408] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     5.422] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     5.423] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     5.463] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     5.463] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[     5.763] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     6.079] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
```

The `intel_drv.so` lib is built/linked correctly (using version `2.99.917+gitAUTOINC+e4fe79cf0d`).

```
ldd /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff28e6b000)
        libpciaccess.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpciaccess.so.0 (0x00007f1de65ce000)
        libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f1de632b000)
        libudev.so.1 => /lib/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f1de6108000)
        libdrm_intel.so.1 => /usr/lib/libdrm_intel.so.1 (0x00007f1de5ee6000)
        libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f1de5cd5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1de5922000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1de5592000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1de5374000)
        /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1de6a2f000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1de516c000)
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/6221f5113f7215433c15cd4e92c889e3) is my entire Xorg log, if it interests you.

Any ideas why my `intel_drv.so` isn't showing up and getting loaded?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC drivers only load if they are needed for the hardware. Your Xorg log shows your X is configured to prefer the `modesetting` driver (which deals with intel hardware through a kernel module), and this driver loads fine. So there's no need for the `intel` driver (and it wouldn't work anyway if the `modesetting` driver is active at the same time).

Comment: This changed after updating the kernel. With 4.9, Xorg wanted intel_drv. After upgrading to 4.14, it want's modesetting. After creating a custom conf file that uses ```Driver "intel"```, it works. What do you mean by "```modesetting``` active"? At a kernel level, or just in Xorg?

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to use intel_drv it because after updating my kernel, I have unwanted scan lines (vsync issues) on the displays that weren't there previously.